# How to pass an argument to a Fragment with Navigation Controller

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-navigation

When using the Android Navigation Controller framework, I'm puzzled how to pass a large and complex object to a fragment. I see you can pass simple fields, integers, strings etc. And I see that you can pass "Parcelable" objects, which is some kind of serializable API. But in my case, I'm trying to display an icon pack, so this is an object with thousands of images, and the idea of somehow serializing thousands of images just to pass it within my program, is ridiculous. Do I have to abandon the Navigation controller, or am I missing something?

Comment: this is not a limitation of navigation component. Regular fragment arguments also rely on primitives/parcelables

Comment: What arguments are you referring to? If it's constructor arguments, that can't be true since you write your own constructor, and you call it. There is no intrastructure between you and the fragment if you are not using the navigation framework.

Comment: Are you talking about the failry recent addition to be able to provide non default constructor for arguments?

Comment: No, I'm saying that if you use Fragments directly, without the navigation framework, your code might look something like this: 
fragmentManager?.beginTransaction()?.apply {
add(android.R.id.content, SomeFragmentIMade(whatever arguments I want go here); commit() },  (note the explicit call to the Fragment constructor), whereas if you're using the navigation framework, your code might look like this:  findNavController().navigate(R.id.some_fragment_i_made), and you don't call the fragment constructure yourself, so you don't have direct access to passing somthing.

Comment: Well you are wrong. Unless you set up a FragmentFactory (which is the fairly new addition I´m talking about) you can´t Use non default constructor for fragments. I mean you can, but you still ned to provide the default one for the framework and that will most likely crash your app. Cheers!

Comment: If you want to use non default constructor, you need a FragmentFactory and set up some DI on your code. I use that AND navigation component and works like a charm.

Comment: "you still ned to provide the default one for the framework"......   Why would you need to provide a default constructor for the framework, when it isn't the framework that is constructing your fragment?  All the fragment tutorials on the internet, including the one at Google, show you creating the fragment yourself. val fragment = ExampleFragment()   https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments

Comment: Do you realise that the example you are just typing is a default constructor without arguments? ". Why would you need to provide a default constructor for the framework, when it isn't the framework that is constructing" yes yes it is. If you rotate your activity and fragments are recreated and the framework is doing it. Don´t believe me? give it a try then. Cheers!

Comment: I see. So.... how are most people passing large and complex objects around to their fragments? I mean, I can use some kind of global variable store, and pass some kind of key to them around as a String or something, but that's not only ugly, it defeats any kind of rational garbage collection.

Comment: It´s not recommended to do it (or it was at least). That being said you can always make your object parcelables and send them through the framgent arguments (Bundle) or you can take a look into FragmentFactory that now allows fragment with non default constructor